# Sphere-Sphere Intersection, choosing right theta

Tags: java, c++, math, 3d, geometry

I am working on a C++ problem where I'm trying to make a utility function that takes as input two line segments starting points in 3d space [(x,y,z) and radius r]. If the segments can be oriented such that they end at the same point, the function should return true and print out that point. If there are multiple orientations that would produce a common endpoint, the function should choose the one that is furthest in the direction indicated by hint_direction.

The function receives these values:

```
bool func(
point3d position_0,               // origin of first line segment.
float length_0,                   // length of first line segment.
point3d position_1,               // origin of second line segment.
float length_1,                   // length of second line segment.
vector3d hint_direction,          // in the event there are multiple solutions, return the one furthest in this direction.
point3d *out_common_end_position) // if result is true, point where both line segments can be oriented to end. otherwise uninitialized.
```

I have been following some guides online which lay out how to do this such as this: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75756/sphere-sphere-intersection-and-circle-sphere-intersection.

I was able to successfully get all the intersecting points, but I cannot figure out how to get a point that is furthest in the hint direction.

I thought I might be able to use the intersection point between circle and hint_direction and get a angle of that point, but I cannot figure out how to do so.

Comment: you can use result of dot product between hint vector and direction to common endpoint however hint direction without origin is meaningless so the hint is relative to what? one of the centers (which) or mod point between centers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Spektre correctly pointed out I missed the 3D portion of your question, so the 4 options are the following:

- no intersection (or one sphere completely lies within the other)
- a single point (spheres touch from inside or outside)
- a normal intersection forming a circle
- both spheres overlap completely, i.e. they have the same origin and the same radius

Since the normal intersection would form a circle you'd want to project the direction hint onto that circle and calculate the intersection between the circle and the projected vector to get the farthest intersection point.

Comment: OP is about spheres (3D) not circles ... so the result possibilities are none, single point, single circle or sphere and then selection of the furthers point using hint if needed. However its not described where the hint direction origins. Using atan2 is overkill for this simple dot product is enough

Comment: @Spektre you're right, I missed the 3D part of this. I'd assume hint direction doesn't have an origin (at least in my mind a direction doesn't have one so the vector describing it could be assumed to have origin 0/0/0).

Comment: Thank you! I assumed the hint direction to have an origin as 0,0,0 too. It was only stated that this direction has to limit to the length or direction.

Comment: @LoviatorShin yes `(0,0,0)` origin is usual origin for direction however I am afraid in this case such origin (not aligned with the spheres itself) might be very impractical / not intuitive. Also how to handle the edge case when your hint is perfectly aligned with the normal of the intersection circle ?